# Handle/Grip bar convention

Tags: jquery, iphone, javascript

Greetings,

Because textarea elements do not resize with jquery.touch ( http://plugins.jquery.com/project/touch ), I've put an textarea in a table where the first row allows the user to drag the table around and resize it with the textarea growing/shrinking/moving along.

It works well, except that users dont seem to 'get' that they can use the bar to resize/move. I was trying to find some 'grip bar' graphics but google isnt helping me.

What is the best way to show users that an element can be moved/resized ? Pointer to graphics ( generators ) would be great. Or, does any one know how to make textarea's movable/resizable ?

T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in the end was that I should not be designing my own UI conventions, so I went back to standard Iphone UI patterns and have a much more intuitive solution now.